# Rolling a dice in a spiral

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dice, spiral

Given a grid size of nxn, a dice is put on the top-left field (1,1) with the number 6 facing down, 5 facing (1,2) and 4 facing (2,1). The dice will roll in a spiral (clockwise) to fill every field with a number (only once). Calculate the total sum of the numbers printed. Visual representation of the moves of the dice and the numbers printed when n=5 (result = 81)

```
01 02 03 04 05
16 17 18 19 06
15 24 25 20 07
14 23 22 21 08
13 12 11 10 09

6 5 1 2 6
4 5 3 2 4
1 1 3 1 1
3 2 3 5 3
6 5 1 2 6
```

This is a homework question, but I can't figure out how to do this efficiently without going through all possible cases. If someone could give me a solution and explanation, that would be amazing (**no code needed, I want to do it myself**).

Comment: I don't really get your question. in particular what does "efficiently without going through all possible cases"  means. You can solve this in 25 relatively straightforward iterations. Are you trying to come up with a *formula* that, given *n*, will solve it in constant time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible clean way t do this is by define a class Dice as mentioned below.

```
class Dice
{
public:
    Dice();
    int face_down();
    void roll_west();
    void roll_east();
    void roll_north();
    void roll_south();
    void set_initial_config(int face_down,int east,int north,int west,int south);
    ~Dice();
private:
    /// variables for your state etc
};
```

If you implement Dice successfully then rest of work will be simple simulation of the rolling of the dice.

```
int roll(int n,int m){ // grid dimensions

    std::vector<std::vector<bool> > visited(n,std::vector<bool>(m,0));

    int i=0,j=-1;
    int dir=0;
    bool dir_changed;
    int dir_change_count=0;
    int sum=0;
    Dice d;

    while(dir_change_count<4){

        dir_changed=0;
        switch(dir){
            case 0:
                if(j+1<m and !visited[i][j+1]){
                    j++;
                    visited[i][j+1]=1;
                    d.roll_east();
                }else{
                    dir_changed=1;
                    dir++;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(i+1<n and !visited[i+1][j]){
                    i++;
                    visited[i+1][j]=1;
                    d.roll_south();
                }else{
                    dir_changed=1;
                    dir++;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(j-1>=0 and !visited[i][j-1]){
                    j--;
                    visited[i][j-1]=1;
                    d.roll_west();
                }else{
                    dir_changed=1;
                    dir++;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(i-1>=0 and !visited[i-1][j]){
                    i--;
                    visited[i-1][j]=1;
                    d.roll_north();
                }else{
                    dir_changed=1;
                    dir++;
                }
                break;
        }
        if(!dir_changed){
            sum+=d.face_down();
            dir_change_count=0;
        }else{
            dir_change_count++;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: if you accept the answer, please do upvote the question as well.